# Select multiple Option - Color property won't works for :hover, :focus, :active, :checked selectors

Tags: html, css

I have a  that I need to change the `style` according to what the user defined.
When I try to customize the `: hover`, `:focus`, `:active`, `:checked` selectors, everything works except the `color` property.

I've tried everything, and the color of the text persists in not changing.

Displays black on overlaping, white onclick and active, and black again when leaves.
I'm talking about the `color` of text and not `background-color`, this is working good whith my CSS.

How can I solve with pure CSS?

```css
select option:hover,
option:focus,
option:active,
option:checked {
  font-size: 16px;
  /* working good */
  text-decoration: underline;
  /* working good */
  background: linear-gradient(gray, gray);
  /* working good */
  color: red;
  /* DOESN'T WORK -> DON'T CHANGE COLOR OF TEXT ON :hover, :focus, :active, :checked */
}
```

```html
<select name="my_select" id="my_select" multiple>


  <option style="color: white; background-color: pink;" value="1">Option-1</option>
  <option style="color: white; background-color: green;" value="2">Option-2</option>
  <option style="color: white; background-color: blue;" value="3">Option-3</option>

  [.. more 100 options with diferent colors in styles defined by user ..]


</select>
```

Comment: You are setting the color inline in HTML witch has prioraty over CSS, use `!important` if you have to override it. And take note `background` and `background-color` and the same, so you have no issues there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the `color` attribute on the option elements itself. Therefore on hover it doesn't change. Instead of defining `color: white` on every single option element (which is bad practice anyways), you could assign that color to all option elements in your css file.

Perhaps if that really doesn't fit your use case, for example when `color` isn't always white, you could try using the `!important` keyword:

```css
select option:hover, option:focus, option:active, option:checked {
    
    font-size: 16px; /* working good */
    text-decoration: underline; /* working good */
    
    background: linear-gradient(gray,gray); /* working good */

    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Solved wit "!important;" thank you very much. I understand your suggestion, I'm aware of that, but for what I'm developing, one of the requirements is that each <option [color + background-color]> might be customizable by the user. Imagine the combinations of CSSs Classes that I would have to prepare. Do you understand now? May there other solutions, but for the moment it was the one that i found.

Comment: No problem. Yeah with that use case I think you're stuck with this solution. In this case it's okay, but make sure you don't start over using `!important`.